# Как преобразовать список ArrayList<Long>list = new ArrayList<>() в массив long[]?

Tags: java, массивы, список

Подскажите пожалуйста самое оптимальное решение (короткое). Допустим дан  список `ArrayList<Long> list = new ArrayList<>()`, и его надо преобразовать в массив `long[] data`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

красиво через стримы:

```
List<Long> list = new ArrayList<>();
long[] data = list.stream()
        .mapToLong(Long::valueOf)
        .toArray();
```

единственное, что нужно помнить, что в исходном `ArrayList<Long>` могут содежатся `null` значения, и тогда эти `null` значения надо обходить ( иначе будет `NullPointerException`). Обойти `null` можно с помощью `.filter` :

```
long[] data = list.stream()
        .filter(Objecst::nonNull)
        .mapToLong(Long::valueOf)
        .toArray();
```

Comment: Подскажите, а для byte[] аналогично будет?

Comment: нет, для byte[] будет по-другому, потому что в стандарте нет явного ByteStream

Answer (score 7):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Objects;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Long> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(1L);
        list.add(2L);
        list.add(3L);
        list.add(4L);
        long[] longsPrimitive = list.stream()
                .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                .mapToLong(Long::longValue)
                .toArray();
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(longsPrimitive));
    }
}
```

Comment: все бы круто, но требуется `long[]` а не `Long[]` :)

Comment: А пожалуйста, подправил.